# Verified smart contract says beneficiary and token address 0x0000

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

I just deployed a token crowdsale contract here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x043acaa777f3e08d0b25d48c899a681a7a17db37#readContract

When I read smart contract, the tokenReward and beneficiaryWallet both shows 0x00000....

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i realized i haven't run setupCrowdsale 
brrrr....